# Visual Studio 2010 - New Tabbed Window

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tabbed, multiple-monitors

Is there a way to create a new code window in Visual Studio 2010 that is also a tabbed container for other code windows.

As far as I can see the windows will only stack on top of each other once they're undocked from the main window and will only tab when placed back on the original Visual Studio screen.

I find this greatly hinders multi monitor code screens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you install the latest [Productivity Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).  This feature is called "Floating Tab Wells" within that extension.